# WARNING: importing deprecated binding Base.e into xxxxxx in Julia

Tags: julia

I am trying to convert my code from Julia v0.6 to v0.7.  I get the following warnings at runtime:

```
WARNING: importing deprecated binding Base.e into xxxxxx.
WARNING: Base.e is deprecated, use ℯ (\euler) or `Base.MathConstants.e` in module xxxxxx
WARNING: Base.e is deprecated, use ℯ (\euler) or `Base.MathConstants.e in module xxxxxx
WARNING: Base.e is deprecated, use ℯ (\euler) or `Base.MathConstants.e` in module xxxxxx
WARNING: Base.Dates is deprecated, run `using Dates` instead in module Base
```

I did a search project(command shift f) and I typed in "Base.e", "Base.Dates", etc. and there was no mention of it in my code.  **How do I resolve these warnings?**

Note: "xxxxx" is just the placeholder for a real file in my project that I replaced to make this post more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e` (exported from `Base`) *was* the constant representing Euler's number(2.7..., mathematical constant e) in Julia, but it was deprecated in v0.7 and removed in v1.0.

The error you are getting is either caused by your code or the packages/modules your project is importing/using.

It does not have to be `Base.e` since you could also refer to it by `e` alone. So you should either replace all `e`s by `ℯ` (\euler + TAB) or add `using Base.MathConstants` at the top of your code/function etc. If this is due to a package you are using, then you can make changes to the package or inform the package maintainers about it.

The other warning about `Dates` is again another deprecation. I would follow the suggestion by the compiler: `using Dates`.

Even with these warnings your code should be able to run on v0.7. These are the warnings that your code will not run on 1.0, giving errors. By getting rid of these deprecation warnings you will (hopefully) be making your code to run on v1.0, too.

Comment: That helps (a lot).  I will take those steps and let you know if it works!

Comment: So the issues with Base.e are solved.  Thank you for that.  But the issue with dates is as follows: WARNING: Base.Dates is deprecated, run `using Dates` instead in module Base.  However, I do not have a Base module in my code.  Any suggestions(using Dates doesn't fix the issue)

Comment: This seems to be another question. But the solution is to add `using Dates` to top of your code, then restart Julia. Because the julia instance that gave you the warning is already poisoned with the binding to Base.Dates, which is deprecated.